# How to configure perl files in IIS 10?

Tags: perl, iis

Can anybody help me to run Perl files over IIS 10.0? I have tried installing Strawberry Perl and adding the corresponding handler to it. But it didn't work.

I want *.pl files to be executed.

This is the Perl file in my directory:

[image: Perl file in the directory]

This is what I see when I try to access that file in a browser:

[image: IIS Error]

Comment: You also need to make sure that the script is in a directory that's configured as an "application" and that you can see the Handler in that directory's config (should be if it's configured as a Handler at the top of the Site).

Comment: What's in `testPerl.pl`?